# Deleted answer reborn?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-answers, specific-answer, undelete

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19044293/1407017) as "Not an answer" + downvoted it. It got deleted by the moderator and I got back the 1 rep.

> [image]

However, the poster of the answer seems to have commented on the answer and as a result some voodoo magic got back the deleted answer.

> [image]

Is that supposed to happen?

---

**EDIT**

Well now it has disappeared again. But I did see it undeleted for a moment there.

Comment: It looks like that post was deleted by the poster himself, not a moderator. He would therefore be able to undelete it. Although it is currently deleted, actually. I can't tell if it was ever undeleted or not -- is there any chance you saw a cached page?

Comment: @JeremyonVacation Does the flag say "helpful" even if the post is deleted by poster? I thought it said that only when moderator deletes it.

Comment: @JeremyonVacation No I got a notification when poster commented on it. I clicked on the notification and was able to see the answer

Comment: "Helpful" doesn't always indicate that the flag was handled by a moderator. If the flagged post is deleted, the system assumes that it no longer needs attention but must have been unsuitable since it was deleted, so it marks the flag as helpful automatically. (As you can imagine, there are some cases where this might not be entirely appropriate. There have been some questions discussing that here on meta.)

Comment: It looks like Jeremy's correct... the poster was just being nice and undeleted to comment and say thank you for informing him.

Comment: I actually thought there is some voodoo magic here (bit disappointed that its not). Thanks Jeremy and Ben for clarifying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at [it's revision (10K)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19044293/revisions) the post was **not deleted by the moderator** but it was deleted by that user himself. So what he did is first he deleted the answer then undeleted the answer then added the comment then again deleted the answer.

Comment: Hmm, I assumed that the `/revisions` page wasn't cached, but I guess it actually is cached for some time... those deletion events didn't show up when I checked the revisions after reading this post.